# How to apply a torque in an FEA simulation in Solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

I am modeling a hollow cylinder as an analog for a bone in Solidworks, but am having difficult applying a torque to it in the SimulationXpress function. I can apply a uniformly distributed load or pressure, but I don't see an option to quickly apply a torque. Does such a thing exist in Solidworks, or do people simulation the effects of torque by applying a number of point forces in different directions?

Comment: Perhaps if you tried asking this in the solidworks api, you should get an answer: https://forum.solidworks.com/community/simulation

Answer (score 0):

Applying Torque exists in Solidworks Simulation.
make new study, set the type as static. In the simulation tree manager; you may find an option "External Loads", right click on it, you will find Torque option as the third from the first option at the top.
Hope that help.
Good Luck.